# What's the word for the backup person for an anchor

Tags: word-usage

Let's say Tom is the anchor for a news program. His colleague Jane is his backup for that program during his absence. I heard on a radio something like:

> This is Jane 'info' Tom.

I could not catch the exact word from that radio. It just sounds like the word 'info'.

**Questions**: What the word is most likely used in this setting? If this could not be figured out by the information I provided here, what would be the proper word(s) which is likely to be used for this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely is "filling in for" or just "in for," which is what you heard.

Comment: or 'standing in for'

Comment: Are 'standing in for', 'filling in for' and just 'in for' commonly used?

Comment: @dan it’s not an especially common occurrence for it to be used but I would expect “filling in for”.

Comment: On National Public Radio, where I most often hear this type of phrase used, "in for" seems to be the most common.